# Can I access OpenGL support on a Mac by installing Linux?

Tags: macos, opengl, apple-m1

I have a Mac M1 computer running the latest version of macOS, which has limited or no support for OpenGL due to Apple's transition to Metal. However, I need to work with OpenGL for a project. If I install a Linux distribution on my Mac, will I be able to utilize OpenGL? Are there any specific considerations or compatibility issues I should be aware of before proceeding with the installation? Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use OpenGL just fine on macOS. The only caveats are:

1. IIRC, the C API is limited to GL 4.1 ish? (or possibly earlier, can't recall exactly).
2. The shader compiler supported GL 4.5 last time I looked *(which leads to some strangeness, where you can use tessellation shaders [GL4.3], but only if you avoid calling the C api calls - i.e. set everything in the shaders!)*.

In theory you could install linux into a VM (e.g. virtual box), and develop your code there. The only problem with that is that it would end up using your OpenGL drivers on MacOs, so you'd be limited to the same feature set.

I've never tried installing Linux directly onto my Mac, but Id assume the OpenGL driver problem won't magically vanish as a result *(given that you'd still need openGL drivers for the macOS hardware - chances are they'd be worse than the default macOS drivers?)*

Maybe just develop the OpenGL code on macOS? :)